# R: algorithm used by leaps-function for subset-regression

Tags: r, regression, subset

I am not sure does the leaps-function for subset regressions in R give me the right output. I therefore tried to find the algorithm used by the function from the help of the leaps-package, but cannot find an answer.

I'd be glad for any advice on how to find the underlying algorithm.

Thank you!

Comment: Just type `leaps` at the prompt without the parentheses. It will show you the source code. For some functions that are not visisble by default (e.g. `regsubsets()`) it's a bit more tricky and you will need to find the method and then use `getAnywhere`, eg, `methods(regsubsets)` gives `[1] regsubsets.biglm*   regsubsets.default* regsubsets.formula*` and `getAnywhere( regsubsets.default)` shows the source code for the default subset regression.

Comment: I probably asked in a bad way - I meant the mathematical formula, which I can, with my very limited knowledge of R, not see from this :/ Thank you nevertheless for the clarification!

Comment: Oh ok. You are looking for [**this book**](http://www.amazon.com/Subset-Selection-Regression-Second-Editon/dp/1584881712).